# Fstab after reboot does not work

Tags: mount, fstab

I have a problem with the mount Windows directory.

1. (terminal) I mount:

   ```
   mount.cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o user=wega
   ```

   and it works.
2. When I go to `/etc/fstab` and add:

   ```
   //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 cifs
   credentials=/root/.smbcredential_2,iocharset=utf8,sec=ntlm 0 0
   ```

After reboot it did not work:

```
.smbcredential_2 file
username=wega   
password=1234
```

Comment: You can add this `mount.cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o user=wega` in your /etc/rc.local before `exit`. It should mount your smb share without any problem.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I did `mount.cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o user=wega
exit 0`, reboot system and df -h and there is no //192.168.1.51 drive

Comment: `exit 0` should be on the next line

Comment: so "exit 0", this is the next line

Comment: its work, I add password `mount.cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o user=wega,password=1234`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add this: `mount.cifs //192.168.1.151/_wymiana /mnt/share_2 -o user=wega,password=1234` in your `/etc/rc.local` before `exit 0` which should be on the next line. It should mount your `smb/share` without any problem.